# Can't get IIS WMI information in ASP.Net web application

Tags: asp.net, iis, wmi

**Operation System**: Windows 2008 R2 Web Server Edition

**Problem**:  Can not get IIS information of local server via `Win32_PerfRawData_W3SVC_WebService` class in ASP.net 4.0 Web Application

**Background**:

1. I can get information `Win32_PerfRawData_W3SVC_WebService` in VBS script on the server.

   strComputer = "."
   Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
   Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
       "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_W3SVC_WebService WHERE Name='Cms2012'",,48)
   For Each objItem in colItems
       Wscript.Echo "CurrentConnections: " & objItem.CurrentConnections
   Next
2. I tried to granted the permission in **wmimgmt.msc**. Enable both IIS_IUSRS and IUSR, but it does not help

Please can someone help me why I can't get the information from following code? it succeed in my test machine.

```
 ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_W3SVC_WebService WHERE Name='Cms2012' ");
 using (ManagementObjectSearcher managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(managementScope, query))
 {
     using (ManagementObjectCollection coll = managementObjectSearcher.Get())
     {
         foreach (ManagementObject obj in coll)
         {
             iisStatus.Add( string.Format("Current connections: {0}", obj["CurrentConnections"]) );
             iisStatus.Add( string.Format("Current anonymous users: {0}", obj["CurrentAnonymousUsers"]));
             iisStatus.Add( string.Format("Current non anonymous users: {0}", obj["CurrentNonAnonymousUsers"]));
             iisStatus.Add( string.Format("Maximum connections: {0}", obj["MaximumConnections"]));
             iisStatus.Add( string.Format("Service up time: {0} seconds", obj["ServiceUptime"]));
             iisStatus.Add( string.Format("Bytes received: {0:N2}MB", (ulong)obj["TotalBytesReceived"] / 1024.00M / 1024.00M));
             iisStatus.Add(string.Format("Bytes sent: {0:N2}MB", (ulong)obj["TotalBytesSent"] / 1024.00M / 1024.00M));
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you tell exactly on which line do you get the error or unexpected null value is returned?

Comment: There is no error,  but can't get the information

Comment: I had the same problem a few weeks ago and creating a windows service with **local system** user solved the problem. every other attempt such as granting permissions or logging in as administrator seemed to fail for unknown reasons for me. However if obj["<name>"] returns null or empty here, but returns another value somewhere else, then the issue is most likely to be **access permission**.

Comment: in my code above, the collection is empty after the query. and I have try to execute the VBS from Background point 1 in ASP.Net, same result and no collection.  I tried the solution ImpersonateLoggedOnUser but it does not help.  It is very strange I always can't retrieve the information from the ASP.Net application. your suggestion is another approach but it complicate the deployment.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not good with web apps, but there are some hints in MSDN (I searched wmi asp in google). If you haven't looked there maybe you find some directions there.